# Conditionally mutate on partial string match across data frames of different lengths R/dplyr/stringr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have two data frames of different lengths, all strings. Let's say:

```
NameDF <- data.frame (names  = c("Jane","John"))
JobDF <- data.frame (occupation  = c("Frank is a teacher","Jane is a doctor","John cooks part-time","Mike was a musician","Jane is an engineer"))
```

In the real dataset, NameDF is a user-specified column that will vary between 2-5 names (rows). JobDF will vary between 65-70 rows long. Sometimes the names in NameDF$names appear more than once in JobDF$occupation. Both will vary in content each time the script is used.

My goal is to create a new column in JobDF called **inNameDF** depending on whether the name appears or not in NameDF.

My intended output looks like this:

```
JobDF
rowID      occupation        inNameDF
1      Frank is a teacher       no
2      Jane is a doctor         yes
3      John cooks part-time     yes
4      Mike was a musician      no
5      Jane is an engineer      yes
```

Because NameDF and JobDF will always vary in content and length, I started off by using %in%. But that doesn't work because I need partial string detection to pattern match in JobDF$occupation. I then moved to using grepl, but that only detects the first row (in my example, Jane), and not the others. The closest I've gotten is this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
JobDF %>% 
   mutate(inNameDF = ifelse(str_detect(occupation, NameDF$names),"yes","no"))
```

This gives a similar warning message as grepl in that it only processes the last instance of the first case in NameDF (the last instance of Jane). At this point I've been spinning my wheels for a few days now, and would appreciate any insight on how to get that JobDF$inNameDF column. I'm also open to non-dplyr/stringr solutions. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

JobDF %>% 
    mutate(inNameDF = ifelse(str_detect(occupation, paste0(NameDF$names, collapse = "|")),"yes","no"))
```

The output of `paste0` is this:

```
paste0(NameDF$names, collapse = "|")

[1] "Jane|John"
```

Which is a regular expression to match "Jane" *or* "John". If you need the match to be case insensitive then wrap it in `stringr::regex` like so: `regex(paste0(...), ignore_case = T)`.

---

If the name was always the first word then you could also do something like:

```
ifelse(sapply(str_split(JobDF$occupation, " "), `[[`, 1) %in% NameDF$names, "yes", "no")

[1] "no"  "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes"
```

Which extracts the first word from `occupation` and checks if it is `%in%` `names`.

Comment: These solutions worked like a charm! I never considered using the regularity of the name coming first to my advantage, either. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse the `names` in  `NameDF` in one string with word boundaries (`\\b`) and use `ifelse` to assign `'yes'` and `'no'`. Word boundaries are needed so that `'Jane'` does not match with `'Janesen'` etc.

```
JobDF$inNameDF <- ifelse(grepl(paste0('\\b', NameDF$names, '\\b', collapse = '|'), 
                         JobDF$occupation), 'yes', 'no')
JobDF

#            occupation inNameDF
#1   Frank is a teacher       no
#2     Jane is a doctor      yes
#3 John cooks part-time      yes
#4  Mike was a musician       no
#5  Jane is an engineer      yes
```

Comment: I really like this approach and see how it can be used in a variety of arenas! Thank you so much for your help.